# Spring Config file consisting of List of Implementations

Tags: java, spring, configuration, dependency-injection

I Am very new to Spring. I have an Interface (MessageHandler ) which has a get method, this method returns a list of Implementations of another interface (messageChecker).

```
public interface MessageHandler {
   public void process(BufferedReader br);
   public void setMessageCheckerList(List mcList);
   [B]public List getMessageCheckerList();[/B]
 }
```

In my Spring XML configuration , i have something like this ,along with other beans

```
<bean id="messageHandler" class="com.XXX.messagereceiver.MessageHandlerImpl">
  <property name="messageCheckerList" ref="checkerList"/>
 </bean>

 <bean id="checkerList" class="java.util.ArrayList">
  <constructor-arg>
   <list>
    <ref bean="HL7Checker"/>
   </list>
  </constructor-arg>
 </bean>

 <bean id="HL7Checker" class="com.XXX.messagereceiver.HL7CheckerImpl">
     <property name="messageExecutor" ref="kahootzExecutor"/>
 </bean>
```

Here i am passing a checkerlist - which is a list of Implementations ( For now i have only 1) of the Interface (messageChecker)

Checkerlist is containing references to Bean Id's which are actual implementaions.

HL7Checker is an implementation of an Interface messageChecker.

But when i run the main program, When i inject the bean "messageHandler" and call the getMessageCheckerList, It returns a null value. These getter and setter methods are working fine without using spring.

I am not sure what seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the answer for you troubles, but I would check:

- is the setter `setMessageCheckerList(List)` in `messageHandler` bean called? (either using some debugger or some trace output like `System.out...`). If it's not, there's probably something wrong with your Spring XML configuration setup. The bean definition you posted requires the property to be set and Spring wouldn't create the `messageHandler` bean without setting the property.
- who calls the `setMessageCheckerList(List)` setter? Or even more precise, what code writes to the field which stores the value of the property? Maybe the field is initialized properly by Spring but gets overwritten to `null` later on?
- are you sure you call the `getMessageCheckerList` on the very same object Spring has configured for you (that is, the `messageHandler` bean). The definition you have posted clearly states an instance of `MessageHandlerImpl` is created by Spring, but it doesn't prevent other instances to be created in other ways. So maybe the instance created by Spring holds the proper value, but you run the `get...` on a wrong instance?

Comment: Thanks Grzegorz, I had acidently created a new messagehandler in my implementation. Its working fine now.